# Convert list input to string out

Tags: python, list

I have a list as below, may I know how do I convert to strings output?

```
Input
A = [['I', 'love', 'apple','.'], 
     ['Today', 'is', 'Sunday', '.'], 
     ['How', 'are', 'you'],
     ['What', 'are', 'you','doing']]

Output
I love apple.
Today is Sunday.
How are you
What are you doing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use:

```py
for row in X:
    print(' '.join(X))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a `for` loop to iterate through each list nested in the list `A`.

```py
A = [
    ['I', 'love', 'apple.'],
    ['Today', 'is', 'Sunday.'],
    ['How', 'are', 'you'],
    ['What', 'are', 'you', 'doing']
]

for row in A:
    print(' '.join(row))
```